# Shade Smooth gives weird results

Tags: mesh

As soon as I do my model "Shade Smooth" I get all kinds of weird distortions.
How is this possible and how can I solve this?

What I've already done is the following, Delete loose, Merge by distance and Tris to Quads. [image]

Comment: This problem is not any mesh problem. It is because of smoothing. You should use the auto smooth feature. I've explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy. Go to the object data properties panel (The one that has an upside down triangle with three verticies) and under normals, click auto smooth. to get the desired result you can change the angle of the auto smooth.

Comment: Solved, thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @MIck You might consider accepting Chaudhry's answer, please read here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you solved my problem also